# How to sort JSON into an array based on a child property

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, for-loop

I've got an RESTful call that's returning data that resembles the following:

```
[{
  name: "one",
  dayID: "Tuesday},
 {
   name: "two",
   dayID: "Monday"
 },
 {
   name: 'three'
   dayID: "Tuesday
 }]
```

What I'm trying to do is iterate over the data and create a new array that has a nested structure based on a unique attribute. So if the array already has a Monday, push the json to that object. If not, make a new one. In this case nesting all objects under the day, so the new array would look like this:

```
[{"Monday":["two"]}, {"Tuesday":["one", "three"]}]
```

These won't be strings in practice, they'll be additional objects but for the sake of simplicity I'm asking for strings in my example. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Show what you have tried. There are lots and lots of similar questions on this site. The objective here isn't to write code for you but to help you fix **your code**

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, I wanted to see how people would approach this.

Comment: By using `Array.reduce` -> https://jsfiddle.net/thgvvm05/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of array you could just return object since keys will be unique.

```js
var data = [{
  name: "one",
  dayID: "Tuesday"
}, {
  name: "two",
  dayID: "Monday"
}, {
  name: 'three',
  dayID: "Tuesday"
}]

var result = data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  if (!r[e.dayID]) r[e.dayID] = [e.name];
  else r[e.dayID].push(e.name);
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Array.reduce` to update your array into the desired format.

You just need to keep updating the `accumulating array acc` as per the condition.

```js
var data = [{
  name: "one",
  dayID: "Tuesday"},
 {
   name: "two",
   dayID: "Monday"
 },
 {
   name: 'three',
   dayID: "Tuesday"
 }];
 
 data = data.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if(acc.some(a => a[cur.dayID])) {
    acc.forEach(a => {
       if(a[cur.dayID]) {
         a[cur.dayID].push(cur.name)
       }
    });
  } else {
    var obj = {};
    obj[cur.dayID] = [cur.name];
    acc.push(obj);
  }
  return acc;
 }, []);
 
 console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Array#reduce with a helper object:

```js
var arr = [{
    name: "one",
    dayID: "Tuesday"
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    dayID: "Monday"
  },
  {
    name: 'three',
    dayID: "Tuesday"
  }
];


var helperObj = {};
var result = arr.reduce(function(r, o) {
  if(!helperObj[o.dayID]) {
    helperObj[o.dayID] = [];
    r.push({ [o.dayID]: helperObj[o.dayID] });
  }
  
  helperObj[o.dayID].push(o.name);

  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```